# Confidence Interval - Meaning and Interpretations

Tags: order-statistics, confidence-interval

Could someone please help me understand what exactly "Confidence" in confidence interval actual means?

1. Does it mean, that, (**on average or exactly?)**, we can say, that (for a 90% confidence interval) confidence intervals drawn for 90% of the samples will contain the true value of the estimate?
2. Is a confidence interval for a confidence level only defined for ordered data/sorted in order? As in, to find a confidence interval of a dataset which is randomly generated, we must sort it in order?
3. Might be related to question (2), How is a confidence interval for a percentile different from point (1), if at all?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Interpretation) for starters

Comment: A 90% confidence interval, for example, comes with the interpretation that if we were to repeat our experiment/study many times and calculate a new confidence interval each time, then we'd expect 90% of those confidence intervals to contain the true value.

Comment: Understood, any insights on 2nd or 3rd would be helpful, as i am a stats noob, please let me know if my questions are idiotic.

Comment: @Jaimeblt1 I don't understand the premise of your second question. Can you give an example of a CI and explain how you think ordering the data is required to compute it?

Comment: Say, I had 100 data points, which are random or not in any order. I think of confidence interval as covering a certain area under curve for a probability distribution if that makes sense? (specifically, in this case a left tailed). Now, would it be right to say if i cover 90 observations from right to left, which are not in any order and term that as 90% confidence level /interval? Please point out what is seemingly wrong in this.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is, how is the concept of a percentile implicit in the idea of a confidence interval/level? Could you explain this in simple terms?

Comment: @Jaimeblt1 There are a lot of points to unpack in your remarks and it is difficult to do  so precisely and in full generality.  I would recommend first reading up on some background of CIs and then post a precise question using a specific example (e.g. computing asymptotic CI for population mean).  Did you read the wiki article on CIs?  You can also check out [this](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter8/8_1_0_intro.php) site.

Comment: Yes i did read the wiki, and I do understand. I am merely struggling with a specific example or application. Thank you for the link, i will try and read up more, i will get back to you.